# Android: FBConnect error

Tags: android, fbconnect

I am  getting the following error while using a sample code of FBConnect. Earlier i was using Facebook rocket, but suddenly it started throwing some exceptions. Now when i am trying FBConnect it's also giving some errors:

```
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://www.facebook.com/login.php?connect_display=touch&fbconnect=1&api_key=1fb0a3d3903ac1838da1668143e64ecc&next=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBDialog.loadURL(FBDialog.java:687)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBDialog.loadURL(FBDialog.java:647)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBLoginDialog.loadLoginPage(FBLoginDialog.java:73)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBLoginDialog.load(FBLoginDialog.java:84)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBDialog.show(FBDialog.java:609)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBLoginActivity.onCreate(FBLoginActivity.java:34)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-28 20:32:29.779: ERROR/FBDialog(261):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kkkkk So i did it by another way.....
I was not able to solve this issue but some how got it working using Android-facebook-Sdk:

Below is the link to download it, read the "Readme" file inside it:
http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk

Hope it will help you Sandeep.

Answer (score 0):

The Android-facebook-sdk log with this url http://touch.facebook.com/login.php.
I do the same in the file FBLoginDialog.java, now I can connect on facebook page (it's a html page). Maybe the answer is here try to find what you need to pass or change on the request to be able to send feed.